# How can I set up a tax rate for all countries?

Tags: tax, export

I want to sell my products in every country in the world for a fixed tax rate on all my products. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

In order to setup a fix tax rate,you need to follow process::

- Add New Attribute with the attribute settings select Fixed Product
  Tax from the drop-down menu Catalog Input Type for Store Owner
- Assign that attribute to  Attribute Sets
- Add tax to product  from manage product
- By default, fixed product taxes are disable so in addition to all the
  above things you also need to enable fixed product taxes. To do this
  go to *System menu > Configuration > Tax button in the Sales section on
  the left > Fixed Product Taxes panel on the right*. Then set the Enable
  FPT drop-down menu to Yes. and click on the Save Config

See [more detail here](http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/fixed-product-taxes)